# Why is Visual Studio loading a different Javascript file than the one in the solution?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I've been working on a fairly simple ASP.net project with some javascript to show and hide some content on the page. Every now and then I'll make some changes to my javascript and they won't show up when I run the project again. Going into debug mode, Visual studio (or internet explorer I guess?) just skips over the changes I made.

This only happened to me once in VS12 and I noticed that the debugger showed a functions(dynamic).js as it went through the steps and a separate functions.js where I had made my changes. I resolved this issue by renaming my javascript file.

My project has moved to VS10 since then and this issue keeps happening more and more frequently.

Any insight as to why this could be happening?

Comment: Sounds like caching, that happens in browsers too. A common way to avoid it is to append a time or date stamp for the last change to the file, like `<script src="file.js?t=2013072">`

Comment: Press SHIFT + REFRESH to see if the new JS is loaded.

Comment: If the browser is caching the javascript so that it isn't showing the latest changes, as bfaveretto is suggesting, then try refreshing the browser page (press F5), perhaps? Also, try using the IE debugging tools as you will be able to see which files are being loaded with the web page.

Comment: As @bfavaretto says, you can break the cache by adding something unique to the JS file. I personally prefer `somefile.HASH.min.js` instead of using a querystring. I personally do this in a [custom build script that versions JS and CSS files for me.](https://github.com/ChaseFlorell/Powershell-Snippets/blob/master/version-javascript-css.ps1)

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, time stamping will definitely work, I'll try refreshing the browser cache, that seems like an easier solution!

Comment: [Here's the reasoning for not using a querystring](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/)

Comment: Interesting read, is there any way that I can mark this question as answered even though it doesn't have an answer? Or should I just leave it?